# openssl returns Bad Magic Number

Tags: c#, encryption, openssl, aes, rijndaelmanaged

In my Linux machine i have a binary AES encrypted file:

```
head -c 100 Leela_Turanga.plr
�|�XѨ��>��c��N�Ώڤ�LW�M��t�p5=c.4���ᑸ�#Owl����M�d��>�ٷa�L�r|��ć�ڐ,��:����#�����\
```

Also i know that the file has been encryped using the password:

```
h3y_gUyZ
```

I am able to decrypt this file using .NET's RijndaelManaged class in the following routine:

```
public static bool decryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        string s = "h3y_gUyZ";
        UnicodeEncoding unicodeEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] bytes = unicodeEncoding.GetBytes(s);
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);
        RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(bytes, bytes), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        FileStream fileStream2 = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);
        try
        {
            int num;
            while ((num = cryptoStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
            {
            fileStream2.WriteByte((byte)num);
            }
            fileStream2.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            fileStream2.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
            File.Delete(outputFile);
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }
```

Since im on Linux I embedded this code in a c# program which i run with **mono**, after i compiled it with mcs.

```
mcs *.cs -out:mybinary.exe
mono mybinary.exe d Leela_Turanga.plr outputfile.dat
```

Where the **d** parameter executes the aforementioned function, **Leela_Turanga.plr** is the file to decrypt and **outputfile.dat** is the resulting decryped file.
This works fine: I can decrypt the file correctly, and i am able to say this because human readable text appears in the decrypted file.
Now i want to decrypt the same file with **openssl**.
First of all i need to get the algorithm parameters, and since the code above works, I modified it to give me these informations:

- Key Size
- AES operation mode (cbc, ecb, pcbc, cfb...)
- Padding (have no idea what that is)

by adding some code:

```
public static bool decryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        string s = "h3y_gUyZ";
        UnicodeEncoding unicodeEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] bytes = unicodeEncoding.GetBytes(s);
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);
        RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(bytes, bytes), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        FileStream fileStream2 = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);


        //=======DEBUG INFO=======
        //PRINT ALGORITHM SETTINGS
        Console.WriteLine(rijndaelManaged.Mode);    //what AES mode are we using?
        Console.WriteLine(rijndaelManaged.KeySize); //what is the keysize?
        Console.WriteLine(rijndaelManaged.Padding); //what is the padding?
        //========================


        try
        {
            int num;
            while ((num = cryptoStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
            {
            fileStream2.WriteByte((byte)num);
            }
            fileStream2.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            fileStream2.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
            File.Delete(outputFile);
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }
```

What it comes out is that RijndaelManaged is working in CBC mode, with a 256 bit key and PKCS7 Padding (again no idea if that is important).
Now i can try using openssl to decrypt:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in Leela_Turanga.plr -out out.bin
```

Then the password prompt appears, I enter the pass, and a "bad magic number" error is returned"

```
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
bad magic number
```

And i get no decrypted file.

Why does openssl say that? I have searched on the internet but I haven't found my answer.

Also:
Since in c# strings are encoded in UTF-16 (hence 16 bits in a char), and the key is "h3y_gUyZ" which are 8 chars, shouldn't the key be 16 x 8 = 128 bits wide? instead of the 256 rijndaelManaged.KeySize returns.

Comment: Note that using the password as key and the key as IV is insecure. The key should be derived from the password, e.g. using `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` and the IV should be indistinguishable from random.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does openssl say that?

OpenSSL uses it's own key derivation routine called EVP_BytesToKey, which takes a salt. This salt is prefixed with a 8 byte magic: `Salted__` in ASCII encoding. Passwords should not be directly used as keys, so OpenSSL converts them to keys first.

You can instead provide a key using -K and then the hexadecimal representation of your string (read on for the encoding). You will also need to provide the IV (in your case the same bytes).

> Since in C# strings are encoded in UTF-16 (hence 16 bits in a char), and the key is `"h3y_gUyZ"` which are 8 chars, shouldn't the key be 16 x 8 = 128 bits wide instead of the 256 `rijndaelManaged.KeySize` returns?

Yes, probably you asked the Rijndael class for the key size *before* initializing it with the key. And note that .NET uses UTF-16LE (little-endian) as the whole ecosystem is in (stupid) little-endian.

---

PKCS#7 is a standard that *contains* a padding scheme. It is both used by .NET and OpenSSL, so that's fine. It is required as ECB and CBC mode require the input size of the cipher is N times the block size of the cipher. So PKCS#7 adds 1 to 16 bytes (the block size of AES) valued `\x01` to `\x10`. Unpadding removes these.